# addChild(); - Adding a movieclip to a frame in AS3

Tags: actionscript-3, textbox, addchild

I am trying to create a function which adds a text box (a blue rectangle) and a textfield on the box. I have a class in the library named textBox, no external classes used.
I started actionscript 3 (before even learning many of the programming fundamentals) about a month ago, so I am not experienced with this.

```
function createTextBox() {
    var textBoxCoordX:int = 305;
    var textBoxCoordY:int = 80;
    var dialogueBox:textBox = new textBox;
    var dialogueText:TextField = new TextField();

    addChild(dialogueBox);

    dialogueBox.x = textBoxCoordX;
    dialogueBox.y = textBoxCoordY;
    dialogueText.x = textBoxCoordX+5;
    dialogueText.y = textBoxCoordY+5;
    dialogueText.text = "Insert Text Here";
}
```

After playing, I immediately get two errors that link me to "var dialogueBox:textBox = new textBox;" These errors' descriptions say "1046: Type was not found or was not a compile-time constant: textBox." and "1180: Call to a possibly undefined method textBox."

Comment: Problem with exporting the `textBox` class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ensure that the linkage is set. Right click, advanced, tick Export for ActionScript.

Comment: Thank you, this fixed the problem straight away.

Answer (score 1):

i think no find textBox movieclip,
You must determine the library has the movieClips and the linkedname called textBox.

Comment: Along with defining a MovieClip in your library as the textBox class (as mentioned above) you could alternatively create a new class file if you are comfortable doing that as well; however, the link identifier (class) for the MovieClip in the library is generally easier and actually will generate it's own class when you go to publish it. You can then make as many textboxes as you want. var dialogueBox:textBox = new textBox();